On-Axis Magnetic Field of a Finite Continuous Solenoid
I am attempting to verify the equation for the magnetic field on axis of a finite continuous solenoid posted to this wikipedia page.
The equation is
$$
B_z = \frac{\mu_0 NI}{2} \left( \frac{\frac{l}{2} - z}{l \sqrt{R^2 + \left(\frac{l}{2} - z\right)^2}} + \frac{\frac{l}{2} + z}{l \sqrt{R^2 + \left(\frac{l}{2} + z\right)^2}} \right).
$$
where $N$ is the number of turns, $I$ is the current, $l$ is the full length of the solenoid, $R$ is the solenoid radius, and $z$ is the axial position.
Following what is currently reference #9 on that article (Caciagli, 2018, starting at equation 3), I can get to the following form:
$$
B_z = \frac{\mu_0 NI}{2} \left( \frac{\frac{l}{2} - z}{l \sqrt{R^2 + \left(\frac{l}{2} - z\right)^2}}\left(\frac{P_2(k_-)}{\pi/2}\right) + \frac{\frac{l}{2} + z}{l \sqrt{R^2 + \left(\frac{l}{2} + z\right)^2}}\left(\frac{P_2(k_+)}{\pi/2}\right) \right).
$$
If I could just show somehow that the $P_2$ functions are both equal to $\pi/2$, then everything would work out great! However, this is proving to be beyond my ability. Can anyone help me either finish this derivation or identify an alternate source?

Unfortunately, that paper is not freely available (I get it via the library), so I will do my best to provide details as to what $P_2$ is:
$$
    P_2(k) = -\frac{\gamma}{1 - \gamma^2} (\mathcal{P} - \mathcal{K}) - \frac{1}{1 - \gamma^2} (\gamma^2 \mathcal{P} - \mathcal{K}),
$$
where
$$
\gamma = \frac{\rho-R}{\rho+R},
$$
and $\rho$ is the radial coordinate which should be equal to zero on axis... this mystifies me because $\gamma = -1$, so $P_2$ seems to always be undefined.
Next we have an elliptic integral of the 3rd kind,
$$
\mathcal{P} = \Pi\left( 1-\gamma^2, \sqrt{1-k^2}\right) = \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\left( 1-(1-\gamma^2)\sin^2 \theta\right)\sqrt{1-(1-k^2)\sin^2 \theta}}
$$
and the first kind,
$$
\mathcal{K} = K\left( \sqrt{1-k^2}\right) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-(1-k^2)\sin^2 \theta}}.
$$
In the case where $\rho = 0$, we get the simplification $k = k_+ = k_- = 1$. Evaluating these elliptic integrals in Mathematica via EllipticK[0] and EllipticPi[0, 0] gives me $\pi/2$ in both cases.
So, I end up with
$$
P_2(1) = \frac{1}{0}\left(0\right)-\frac{1}{0}\left(0\right).
$$
Yuck--this does not seem to equal $\pi/2$! Is there a better way to approach this, or some other source from witch I could site that initial equation?

While this problem hasn't been answered here, it has been addressed previously on the PhysicsSE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113232/magnetic-field-inside-finite-solenoid. In particular, the result amounts to taking the result for a single loop (with vertical position $z'$, for an observer at $z$) and integrating with respect to $z'$ appropriately.
